# Custom Exception in Python - test value of a variable

Tags: python

I want to test if a condition is met for my python script to throw an exception.

I want to test if a variable is set. And if it contains the right value. Here is how my exception is written now:

```
try: 
    aws_account = input(colored("Enter the name of the AWS account you'll be working in: ", 'yellow'))
except:
    print("That is not a valid Company AWS account.")
else:
```

I also want to test in the try: statement if the user input is in the format of: company-${aws_account}. Such as company-lab, company-stage, company-prod, etc.

How can I test if aws_account contains the correct value in the try: statement?

Comment: This should really be an `if/else` condition

Comment: `aws_account = input(...); if aws_account.startswith("company-"): ...; else: ...`

Comment: Ok that's great! Thank you. Now what if I wanted to limit it to certain words. Such as "company-dev, company-qa, company-stage, company-prod" etc? It would cleaner if I were able to do that.

Comment: `if aws_account in ['company-dev', 'company-qa', ...etc]: do_aws_thing; else: print("error")`.  This is really basic stuff though, you should brush up on your tutorials.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am a beginner as should be evident. I am working on it. Thanks for your input.